# Am I understanding the function and its purpose correctly? Also, Syntax Error?

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I am having trouble understanding why i keep getting a syntax error for this function. It returns an int such that n_times (f,n,v) applies f to v n times. For example, n_times((fun x-> x+1), 50, 0) = 50. If n<=0 return v.

```
let rec n_times (f, n, v) =
  (* YOUR CODE HERE *)
   raise (Failure "Not implemented")
assert (n_times((fun x-> x+1), 50, 0) = 50)
```

Here is what I coded:

```
let rec n_times (f, n, v) =
  (* YOUR CODE HERE *)
  |n<=0 -> f v
  |n>0 -> f v * n_times(f, n, v)

  let f() = (Failure "Not implemented2")

let f() = assert (n_times((fun x-> x+1), 50, 0) = 50)
```

I believe for this function v is multiplied n times. Am I understanding this right? Also I don't understand why the first line of my code gives me a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be writing a `match` expression, but you just have the last part (with different alternatives), and not the first part (which says `match ... with`). So the `|` token isn't allowed at the point where it shows up in your code.

As a second comment, the `match` statement takes patterns, and `n <= 0` is not a pattern. It's a boolean expression.

So, more likely you just want to use an `if` statement.